# How is the "designated target hit" point bonus calculated?

Tags: battlefield-3

I've been recently trying to figure out all the changes with the latest Battlefield 3 update and the one that's baffling me a lot is laser designating.

After the patch, if a guided missle/javelin hits a vehicle that you laser designated(and it hit it while you had the designation), you'll get a seemingly random point bonus somewhere from 1-99 points.

Sometimes I'll get two bonuses from two missles that add up to more than 100, so I guess it's not damage. And sometimes, when it hits a smaller vehicle I'll only get 49 points even though the vehicle is destroyed.

What calculation goes into this point bonus?

Comment: one part is probably distance related, also if using a soflam while using laser designate, other can get points and vice versa.

Comment: I'm fairly certain it is damage, and it's just taking into account overkill (assuming that the vehicle dies), I don't know for sure though, because I never have anyone on my team shooting at my soflam targets.

Comment: @MrSmooth if you play with at least one other friend, and you have the third-seat unlocked in the tank, you can become nearly invincible. The third-seat can laser designate, and if the driver has guided missles, then you can lock onto anything and do extremely high damage

Comment: @Earlz Yeah I've done that before the patch, so I never got designation bonuses, but yeah, 2 people with the gunner switching between gunner/designator when vehicles come up is unstoppable.

Comment: Something like this I will try to test tonight and provide some feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Its damage, just remember that if someone is repairing the vehicle or there is a delay between hits, then it is very possible that the score you get will be over 100.